# Fitch Proof Exercise 13.8

Tags: logic, philosophy

I am having trouble solving this Fitch Proof. Here is how far I’ve gotten

[image]

Only the last step is not checked out in Fitch but I think the logic works well.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: You should delete step 7.  You already made the assumption in step 2.

Comment: @DanielV: Except that it's the assumption in a sub-proof. That's how you set up a $\forall$ Intro.

Comment: Step 10 looks right to me. Only thing I can think of is that in 2, you're assuming the $\text{Cube}(b)\land \text{Dodec}(c),$ involving $c,$ whereas in line 11, the rest of your expression involves $y$ instead of $c$.

Comment: Step 7 is the assumption in a sub-proof. Without it i have no idea how to eliminate the ∀ in 6 and get the FrontOf(b, c)

Comment: $\forall$-intro is not supposed to discharge assumptions.  It would be impossible to prove statements like $\forall x.Px \iff Px$ , or $\forall x.Qx \lor \lnot Qx$ if $\forall$ intro had to discharge assumptions.  So I have no idea what is going on with your software.  Probably they have some extraneous rule. 
 But you have to delete step 10, prove *assumption free* the statement  $(Cx \land Dy) \to Fxy$, then use forall intro twice on that statement.

Comment: @DanielV Some texts might use ($\alpha$) instead of ($\beta$), but proof writing software can be less forgiving.$$\begin{array}{l:l} (\alpha) & (\beta)\\\hdashline \raise{4ex}{\begin{array}{|l}\boxed b ~ P(b)\\\hline \vdots\\ Q(b)\end{array}\\\forall x~(P(b)\to Q(b))}&{\begin{array}{|l}\boxed b \\\hline \begin{array}{|l} P(b)\\\hline\vdots\\ Q(b)\end{array}\\P(b)\to Q(b)\end{array}\\\forall x~(P(b)\to Q(b))}\end{array}$$

Comment: @HollyFeng On the other hand Step 10 should not have checked out at all, as it is letting a variable ($c$) escape from its declaration scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{array} {rl}
& \forall x .(Cx \to \forall y. (Dy \to Fxy)) \\
& \quad \boxed{b} \\
& \quad \quad \boxed{c} \\
& \quad \quad \quad Cb \land Dc \\
& \quad \quad \quad \vdots \\
& \quad \quad \quad Fbc \\
& \quad \quad (Cb \land Dc) \to  Fbc \\
& \quad \forall y .(Cb \land Dy) \to  Fby \\
& \forall x .\forall y. (Cx \land Dy) \to  Fxy \\
\end{array}$$

Organizing your proof like this may work.  Unfortunately the software is closed so it can't be openly verified.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping! I've figured it out